# Location of the fuel level sensor?

Tags: fuel-system, hyundai, sensor, santa-fe

- What is the location of the fuel level sensor on a 2008 Hyundai Santa Fe GLS 2.7L V6?
- Is there a special tool needed to remove the fuel level assembly from the gas tank?

"P0464 code: Fuel level sensor A circuit intermittent" is present. After fuel fill up, the gauge works but after 5-6 gallons used, the gauge shows empty or less than 1/2 full. 19.8 gallon tank.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please, in the future, turn down the volume by not using all capital letters. Bad juju on the internet.

Comment: The fuel level sensor is on the side of the fuel pump. You may be able to buy just the float and sensor from a dealership instead of buying a whole new fuel pump.

Comment: thanks for your input. Since my question, according to a video on youtube , the santafe 2007-2009 requires the rear 60/40 seat to be removed. the driverside has the fuel pump & sensor & the passanger side had the 2nd sensor & they recommended replacing both sensors at the same time,not the float but the switch/wire assy(sensor) which are actually potentiometers.if the video is correct,the fuel sender lock tool is needed to remove the cover of the sending unit. If you hear of anyone who replaced these sensors on the santafe,plz forward any info, thanks

Answer (score 2):

> thanks for your input. Since my question, according to a video on youtube , the santafe 2007-2009 requires the rear 60/40 seat to be removed. the driverside has the fuel pump & sensor & the passanger side had the 2nd sensor & they recommended replacing both sensors at the same time,not the float but the switch/wire assy(sensor) which are actually potentiometers.if the video is correct,the fuel sender lock tool is needed to remove the cover of the sending unit. If you hear of anyone who replaced these sensors on the santafe,plz forward any info, thanks

This is correct, but you don't need the lock ring tool. You can use a hammer (use a big hammer) and a flathead screwdriver or chisel to remove the lock ring. You may need a razor blade to cut the carpet a bit to get at the sending unit covers.

Make sure you depressurize the system before you remove the fuel lines or you'll get sprayed in the face. Pull the pump fuse or relay and run the car until it stalls.

All the hose fittings are quick disconnects. Two of them should have locks that need to be removed. There's also a crossover tube that connects both sending units in the tank that has to be disconnected.

The sensors are locked in place by a tab. Depress the tab and they slide off.

Dorman has a kit for this job that comes with both sensors and new seals.

Comment: Let the car sit overnight before working on it, if possible. In my experience running it until it stalls relieves most of the fuel pressure from the system, but not all of it. Wearing eye and ear protection until you're certain it's depressurized is also prudent.

Comment: Also, a large rubber strap wrench could be used to twist the lock ring off.  That's what I always use and it works like charm!

Comment: "use a hammer and screwdriver" that's the worst advise to give someone who dont know what they are doing.....Gas is flammable and metal on metal makes a spark... hello of course your probably still using an incandescent bulb drop light.... if you dont have the right tool use a brass punch and a hammer yes, that is done often....oh yea gas and spark makes fire